# releasing apps with visual studio 2011 express beta

Tags: licensing, visual-studio-express

I downloaded Visual Studio 2011 Express beta and it says it is for debugging, developing, etc. but not for deploying / releasing software or apps.

Am I excluded from releasing anything I develop with it? Can I copy the code over to another (unreleased?) version later?

Is there another (like a paid non-express beta?) version I should consider buying?

I googled it, but didn't see any easy answers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio 11 hasn't been released yet. That's why you can only get a beta version. If you're developing a .NET 4.5 app, that's in beta too. Ditto Windows 8, if it's a Metro app.

If you're only using .NET 4 (or earlier) you can get Visual Studio 2010 ([paid](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-gb/products) or [Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express) editions). Otherwise, just wait until the platform you're developing against is released too...

Answer (score 3):

The express editions of *released* Visual Studio versions for 2005, 2008 and 2010 allow you to deploy and release software created using them.

I wouldn't expect a *beta* to have such permissions because it *is* a beta and may contain bugs and issues that will be fixed by the time the product goes RTM. Would you want to take the chance of this with a production system?

Comment: Anecdotal observations, but much appreciated. +1